# Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch

Tags: java, netbeans, centos

I have just installed Netbeans 8.0.2 on CentOS 6.5.

When I try to run it, I get the message

```
Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch
```

I have /usr/share/java-1.7.0  so I typed

```
/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans --jdkhome /usr/share/java-1.7.0
```

and still got

```
Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch
```

I also have /root/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_40 which allowed me to install Netbeans.  However, when I type

```
/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans --jdkhome /root/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_40
```

I still get

```
Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch
```

I tried

```
whereis java
```

and got

```
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/lib/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

However

```
/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans --jdkhome /usr/bin/java
```

still produces

```
Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch.
```

Comment: recheck please both:
`java -version` , `javac -version`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**I do recommend you to change the configuration of JDK used by NetBeans in `netbeans.conf` config file**:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\..."
```

Comment: I'm using Linux.  However /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/etc/netbeans.conf contains the line netbeans_jdkhome="/root/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_40".  Thanks,

Comment: No.  It is not working.  That line was there immediately after the installation.  Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure the directory still exists and contain bin directory with JDK binaries?

Comment: Yes.  It still exists plus I tried changing that line to netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/bin/java".  It made no difference.  I still get the same error message.  Thanks,

Comment: How do you execute NetBeans. Does the user have rights to read from that directory?

Comment: sudo /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans --jdkhome /root/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java

Comment: This is really weird. Maybe you can dig something out from debug logs from NetBeans?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `sudo /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans --jdkhome /root/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_40` without the `/bin/java` at the end?

Comment: David, I tried that as well but still got the same result.  Thanks,

Comment: I could not find netbeans in /var/log.  Thanks,

Comment: Sp far, I have not had problems with NetBeans on Windows, Ubuntu or Debian.  Maybe it is the CentOS version.

Comment: Works for windows setup.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 29):

1. Go to the netbeans installation directory
2. Find configuration file [installation-directory]/etc/netbeans.conf
3. towards the end find the line netbeans_jdkhome=...
4. comment this line line using '#'
5. now run netbeans. launcher will find jdk itself (from $JDK_HOME/$JAVA_HOME) environment variable

***example:***

```
sudo vim /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/etc/netbeans.conf
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me, using Netbeans on OS X.

Comment: Works for ubuntu 18.04 too. Good job mate

Comment: For editing via notepad you can use command `gedit netbeans.conf` from console, or open this file with explorer as root

Answer (score 4):

### **ATTENTION MAC OS USERS**

---

First, please remember that in a Mac computer the **netbeans.conf** file is stored at

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf
```

(if you had used the default installation package.)

Then, also remember that **the directory** you **MUST** use on either **"netbeans_jdkhome**" or **"--jdkhome"** it's **NOT** the */Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/* **but the following one**:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home //<-- Please, notice the /Contents/Home at the end. That's the "trick"!
```

*Note: of course, you must change the versions for both NetBeans and JDK you're using.*

Answer (score 2):

Check the setting in your user config `/home/username/.netbeans/version/etc/netbeans.conf`

I had the problem where I was specifying the location globally, but my user setting was overriding the global setting.

CentOS 7/Netbeans 8.1

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans 8.2 - Cannot locate java installation in specified jdkhome?

Answer: Edit the netbeans.conf file.

Close NetBeans, start Notepad or another text editor as Administrator. Right click on the Notepad application and choose "Run as administrator" and then open netbeans.conf with it. Change netbeans_jdkhome=”C:\Program Files...whatever”.

Answer (score 1):

Try Java SE Runtime Environment 8. It fixed it for me.

Comment: Netbeans searches JDK HOME by `javac` location (not `java` location), so in my case `java` and `javac` location were differ by error, then it can not find correct JDK HOME location (see source netbeans/platform/lib/nbexec ).

Answer (score 0):

With the Netbeans 10, commenting out the `netbeans_jdkhome` setting in `.../etc/netbeans.conf` doesn't do the job anymore. It is necessary to specify the right directory depending of 32/64 bitness.

E.g. for 64 bit application: `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk8u202-b08"`

Answer (score 0):

If like me, you got that message after installing [jenv](https://www.jenv.be/),
simply add `netbeans_jdkhome="$JAVA_HOME"` to your `[netbeans-installation-directory]/etc/netbeans.conf` file

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had installed *ahem* Open**JDK**, but the bin folder was full of symlinks to the bundled JRE and the actual JDK was nowhere to be found.

When I see a directory structure with `bin` and `jre` subdirectories I expect this to be the JDK installation, because JRE installations on Windows looked different. But in this case it was the JRE installation as found out by `apt search`. After installing openjdk-8-jre the simlinks were replaced and the directory structure otherwise stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following lines to the end of `.profile` file inside your home directory and then logout and login or reboot:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

in which `/path/to/jdk` points to your JDK installation folder. For exapmple `/snap/openjdk/1163/jdk`.

Answer (score 0):

Just "suffered" on Windows and latest Netbeans 19, no way to use something in the PATH variable...

To solve, I've added to the shortcut in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Apache NetBeans" an argument like below:

```
--jdkhome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.7"
```

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is:

- make sure `java` path is available:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

- then in etc/netbeans.conf make sure `netbeans_jdkhome` is commented out
- in Finder go to /bin/ click on netbeans (terminal icon)

You would expect `./netbeans --jdkhome=/usr/bin/java` to work, but it doesn't for some reason.