# Running Netbeans for Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a problem with running Netbeans for Java development..

When I try to run it I get

[image: missing JDK error]

I checked the config located in `<netbeans_dir>/etc/netbeans.conf` and found following setting:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/"
```

So, I checked `java` and `javac`:

```
>>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
>>whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
>>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_151
>>whereis javac
javac: /usr/bin/javac /usr/share/man/man1/javac.1.gz
```

So I updated `netbeans_jdkhome` to `/usr/bin/javac`. Now, when I try to run Netbeans I get

```
Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch.
```

I also tried to reinstall Java according to [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14788468/401499) but once I did and changed `jdkhome` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk` I still get `Cannot find java`.

What should I enter to run Netbeans properly?

Comment: In NetBeans select Tools -> Java Platforms -> Add platform, and browse to the desired JDK folder.

Comment: I already wrote that the path I find seems to not work...

Comment: Well, what is displayed when you select Tools -> Java Platforms (in the **NetBeans** IDE?

Comment: Normally your java installation is in `/usr/bin/jvm/` or something like that.

Comment: It's looking for the base installation directory of the JDK. You pointed it at the singular `javac` binary

Comment: @zlakad In the specified window it shows me only JRE...

@cricket_007 I tried also `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk` but it didn't help either... what value should I enter then?

Comment: It should display **JDK** not JRE!

Comment: Can you please show `echo $JAVA_HOME`? And can you also show the contents of that directory if that variable is not empty?

Comment: Look, I'll post a picture as an answer...

Comment: @cricket_007 variable is empty

Comment: Well, that's the first problem. Netbeans actually looks for that variable. https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java

Comment: Attention Mac OS users: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52959955/2457251

Answer (score 0):

**Tools -> Java Platforms -> Add platform** should display something like this:
[image]

Notice that Platform folder has small rectangle that indicates it can be chosen.

Comment: **export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin**
*(Note: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk" is symbolically used here just for demostration. You should use your path as per your installation.)*
In your comment you used `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk`... If this is the path where you installed your java, just add `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin`

Comment: Ideally, you `export JAVA_HOME`, and then `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`