# Gephi: Requires Java, Cannot find Java 1.8 or higher

Tags: java, gephi, incompatibility

Descirption:
I have downloaded Gephi. I have also installed latest Java.
But still I'm getting error:

> Cannot find Java 1.8 or higher.

I have read solutions to this problem which states to change the .config file to exclude the last java by "#". But still I cannot launch Gephi.

Solution that I tried:

[Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052219/cannot-find-java-please-use-the-jdkhome-switch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of commenting it out, trying to include the path of the JRE.
Commenting it forces the application to automatically find the JAVA.

Try this:
For eg: #jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\"
change this to
jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191\"

Instead of 1.8.0_191, use your version in the following directory.