# gephi cannot find java 1.8 or higher with JDK 16

Tags: java, java-8, gephi, java-16

I've installed JDK 16.0.1 (folder C:\Program Files\Java) and tried to run Gephi but it appears the error "cannot find java 1.8 or higher" so I searched for how to solve this and every answer involves doing something with the JRE directory, so I installed the JRE 8u291, it installed on the same folder as JDK (C:\Program Files\Java), but the solutions say it's supposed to be on the program files (x86) and I tried it so many times i'm so angry please help

Answer (score 1):

please look at https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/1787

I've faced with the same problem.

After pointing gephi to jdk home folder got swing exception after gephi start, UI was not loaded properly.

After installing JRE8 and pointing gephi to JRE home everything is ok.

Comment: The pertinent point: "I recommend you try the workaround explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052219/cannot-find-java-please-use-the-jdkhome-switch (gephi.conf instead of netbeans)"